# Iterate over Python 2D array grouping columns data for total

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration, grouping

I have a 2D numpy array that I am searching by column for groups of 1s, which is fairly simple, this effectively a matrix of 1s and 0s:

```
groups = [list(c) for c in mit.consecutive_groups((mit.locate(data[:, 2])))]
```

Here it is only looking at column #3, I want to get out of it a dictionary of values summed over the whole array by column. I want to do this such that I have a dictionary that shows the number of occurrences of a given group length. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that over even a single column, let alone getting that same value for all columns combined, skipping the first column.

I can use this snippet to get key-value pairs of index a group starts on and versus it's length. But what I want to get is a key of group length with a value of the total number of occurences.

```
d = {group[0]: len(group) for group in groups}
```

I can't think of anyway of rewriting this, with or without conditionals that will get me it for even a single column, let alone modifying my initial line of code to allow me to do it over the entire matrix.

Here's an example of the input data:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
20 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
30 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
40 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
50 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
60 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
70 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
80 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
90 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Ideally I need to also be able to tell if it was at the end of the dataset, as it would have been cut off. So a combination of the method I've been using which doesn't give quite what I need and some other similar method might be the best approach. I simply cannot find a way, been trying all weekend. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a minimum working example?

Comment: Absolutely, sorry I didn't include it to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should perform the desired sorting/transformation on the input data. It will also provide an array of 1s that appear at the end of the data for reference.

```
dataarray = numpy.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[70, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[80, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[90, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

padded = numpy.pad(dataarray,((1,1),(0,0)), 'constant')
colinds, rowinds = numpy.where((padded[:-1] != padded[1:]).T)
lengths = rowinds[1::2] - rowinds[::2]
colinds, rowinds, = colinds[::2], rowinds[::2]
parsed = list(zip(colinds, rowinds, lengths))
lenind = []
d = {}
for row in parsed:
    if(row[-1] not in lenind):
        lenind.append(row[-1])

for i in sorted(lenind):
    d[i] = 0

for row in parsed:
    d[row[-1]] += 1

od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))

for line in parsed:
    if(line[1] + line[2] == len(dataarray)-1):
        print(line)

parsedarray = numpy.array(parsed)

endflips = [j for j in parsedarray if j[1] + j[2] >= len(dataarray)]
```

Data should come out in the format of "column #, row #, length", where length is the number of 1s in a row in that column.